# How to achieve DOM manipulation in languages other than javascript ex:python

Tags: javascript, python, dom

```
InputTags = document.getElementsByTagName("input")

for (inputTag in InputTags) {
  if (inputTag.name == 'username') inputTag.value = "abc"
  else if (inputTag.name == 'password') {
    inputTag.value = "abc@123"
  }
}
```

In the above segment, DOM elements are manipulated by Javascript method "getElementsByTagName".Similarly how do I acheive this in languages like python?

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate DOM elements in an active browser session? What is your use case for this?

Comment: This is just a part of code. In this case,I try to enter username and password for an active browser session...My ques is for understanding DOM manipulation methods in different languages

Answer (score 0):

Most languages have some kind of library for this. Java has jsoup:
https://jsoup.org

Python does come with a built in html parser though you might want to search online for a better library.

Answer (score 0):

There's python standart [XML DOM processors](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html) and there's [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library. Both able to manipulate DOM tree similar to JS.